# Liquibase - custom parameter in createView statement

Tags: java, liquibase, multi-tenant, changelog

I've configured liquibase to work using schema's multi tenant in postgresql. It is working fine when the changelog just creates table or structures that only depend on xml syntax. However, I need create some views that are dependent of the **defaultSchemaName** parameter, so I've tryied this way, without success:

```
<changeSet id="00000000000002_blog_views" author="hudson" dbms="postgresql">
    <createView viewName="blog_post_management_view" replaceIfExists="true">
            SELECT
              p.id,
              p.title,
              ba.name as author,
              p.status,
              p.created_date
            FROM ${defaultSchemaName}.blog_post p
              INNER JOIN ${defaultSchemaName}.blog_author ba ON p.author_id = ba.id
    </createView>
</changeSet>
```

I'm getting this error when executing the above changelog:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$"
Position: 258 [Failed SQL: CREATE VIEW "c7a53124-0ca9-4ce4-a25d-34b1764ee9df".blog_post_management_view AS SELECT
              p.id,
              p.title,
              ba.name as author,
              p.status,
              p.created_date
            FROM ${defaultSchemaName}.blog_post p
              INNER JOIN ${defaultSchemaName}.blog_author ba ON p.author_id = ba.id]
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:309)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:113)
at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1277)
at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1259)
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:582)
... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$"
```

Important to notice that my liquibase runner is already configured with the defaultSchemaName:

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("liquibase")
public MultiTenantSpringLiquibase multiTenantLiquibase(DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {
    MultiTenantSpringLiquibase liquibase = new CustomMultiTenantSpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml");
    liquibase.setContexts(liquibaseProperties.getContexts());
    liquibase.setDefaultSchema(liquibaseProperties.getDefaultSchema());
    liquibase.setDropFirst(liquibaseProperties.isDropFirst());
    liquibase.setSchemas(getSchemas(dataSource));
    if (env.acceptsProfiles(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_NO_LIQUIBASE)) {
        liquibase.setShouldRun(false);
    } else {
        liquibase.setShouldRun(liquibaseProperties.isEnabled());
        log.debug("Configuring Multi Tenant Liquibase");
    }
    liquibase.setParameters(DatabaseUtil.defaultParams(liquibaseProperties.getDefaultSchema()));
    return liquibase;
}
```

Is there a way I can use a property or any kind of system variable in createView tag content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I need add the parameter manually, It appears to me I can't access "defaultSchema" parameter only setting defaultSchema property ( `liquibase.setDefaultSchema("something");`):

```
 Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
 parameters.put("schemaName", schema);
 liquibase.setChangeLogParameters(parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the schema name from the property file:

```
@Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema}")
private String schemaName;
```

Now you can use the `schemaName` variable in your code.